# What's the best way to add a directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: command-line

I installed an application in a non-standard place. When I run it I get

```
error while loading shared libraries: libthrift-0.9.0-dev.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I can fix this by adding the directory to the environmental variable $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but I wonder if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want this to be system-wide, you can add the directory to the `ld.so` configuration. This will make the dynamic linker always check that directory when looking for libraries to load.

To do this, just add a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` (it should end in `.conf`), containing the full path of the directory.